# Django trusted server for file processing-distributing-retrieving

Tags: python, django, file-upload, download

I am a newbie in Django having a project in mind to accomplish and wondering about the proper architecture and path to take towards the following scenario:

I have a trusted server that has the following duties:
1. Authenticates a user 
2. Receives a file from the user and transforms it into n segments by performing an algorithm of mine (presume one like Rabin's IDA or All-or-nothing transform (AONT)), and then stores each produced segment on other pre-defined distinct servers.
3. IN downloading phase, the server authenticates the user, retrieves the segments of the corresponding requested file from storage servers, combines the segments to construct the file and delivers it to the user.

What is opaque for me is the needed elements on the storage sides:
How does the trusted server communicate with the storage severs and retrieves the segments? How can I provide the trusted server to request the storage servers for the file X that belongs to User Y?

What I had in mind was to provide each segment with a specific metadata that could be generated using a hash function that has the file ID and Users ID as inputs.

I would be grateful if you provided me with a road map and elements I would need to consider on each side for this project. An over view suffices. Thank you so much.

Comment: To understand your problem I think we need to know a bit more. Why store the segments on different servers? Are we talking a large amount of data?

Comment: @henrikstroem I would like you to think of my algorithm resembling a secret sharing like Shamir Secret Sharing but with better efficiency and less storage blow-up which makes it possible to recover the data even if some of the storage severs are down. Thus, one of the reasons to store the segments in different locations is to increase the availability (how ever my main goal is security).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to go about this, each with their strengths and weaknesses.

Common for the solutions that comes to me is this setup:

- The trusted server (TS) receives the File in the first place (upload to this server)
- TS applies your algorithm to and get a list of segments (also files)
- Segments may be individually encrypted(?)
- TS stores the metadata in a database like so:

  | User |--<| File |--<| Segment |>-<| Server |
- A File gets an id, say: 338977FE-36F3-4397-BD60-A9CE94146AF0 (UUID) and whatever metadata is needed
- A Segment gets a UUID too, a ForeignKey to the File it belongs to, and the servers it's stored on
- The database stores the Segments in order so they can be assembled into a File again

The File id may be returned to the user for future retrieval, or he can get a list of his Files from TS.

I basically think of two ways TS can send and retrieve Segments from storage servers (let's call them SA, SB, SC ...):

Use a simple web service on storage servers to read and write Segments, e.g. to write you HTTPS POST:

```
sa.storagesyste.com/segments/7FD960E2-7C77-4A17-BB67-813377A83443/
```

To read the Segment, simply HTTPS GET the same URL. This requires a simple web service running on each storage server. Whether you want authentication on the storage servers is up to you, you need to know the exact key to get the file, that may be enough. With this approach, you could also have a desktop client retrieve the Segments itself - on download it would simply get the list of Segment ids and where to download them.

Alternatively, if you're on Unix or Linux, you could use `scp` to transfer the files between TS and storage servers. This way you can use the `SSH` PKI infrastructure of Unix/Linux to add extra security in a manageable way. With this approach the TS need to collect the Segments and regenerate the File, then the user can download.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer, my main concern mostly involves the access part, how can the user have an account and how can he ask for a specific file and how the retrieval process takes place. About your question regarding the encryption I would say, yes. the algorithm first encrypts the file then transforms it into n segments.

Comment: You could compute a hash value for each segment that the user would need to download the file. That's easily verified on the storage servers without the need for them to share the user database with TS.

Comment: > I've been struggling a lot with this project, Do you think socket can be a proper way for uploading and downloading between the TS and storage servers?

Comment: @Miind Unix sockets? That's  for local inter process communication - not between different hosts.

Comment: > a simple client-server socket, having the server listening on a port to receive a remote data

Comment: @Miind Sure you can do that, but you'll be dealing with things on a lower level, making things more complicated.

Comment: > Do you thing using SFTP would be proper idea? does it work on large scale environment?

Comment: > Do you have any project, link or example regarding serving the files from a web service? I have found non thus far :|